# How do I start a new repo on github with an existing project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I built out a project and have been pushing it to git hub. I then made a copy of the folder (on my local machine) and started going in a different direction with it. I created a new repo on github but it won't let me push the changes because it still thinks it's part of the old repo. When I go to change the name, it resets the files on my local machine back to the previous repo! Good thing I saved a copy before trying this.

Basically what I want to do is start a new repo on github with my current project but keep all the git revisions I did in the past. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you must first have to remove your reference to the old repository: (in this case origin is the name of the reference to github)

```
git remote rm origin
```

And add the new reference:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:.....
```

And then push all the commits from your local repository to github

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: this didn't work. i did each step but when i went to do "git push origin master" it said "everything up to date" and nothing in my github repo changed...still has the old files

Comment: I tried and it works ok. Can you go to .git/config in your repository and take a look if origin is pointing to your new repo?

Comment: yes, it does. I tried doing git add . and then git commit and then git push...and then it reverted my local files back to my previous version...which deleted a bunch of files. I have a backup just in case...what should i try now? for some reason it's copying from github to my local instead of the other way around.

Comment: tried it again...got this error:


 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:mberman84/Project.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: That happen because your repository has some commits that your local repo doesn't. Please try this again, make a copy of your dir, in your new dir, verify that you are in the branch you want(for example master); in github create a new repo, follow the instructions from the answer. An in your github will be new repo. Another solution is to make a fork of your current repo on github and rename it :)

Comment: 1) create a bare github project 2) git remote rm origin 3) git remote add origin git@github.com:.... 3) git push -u origin master.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to create a branch:

```
 git checkout -b MyNewBranch
```

then you want to add a new remote to your new github repo:

```
git remote add new_remote  <path_to_new_github>
```

Finally when you push from the branch use

```
 git push new_remote MyNewBranch
```

Comment: basically what i want is to have a new repo on github and start pushing my current changes to the new repo. will what you suggested do the trick?

Comment: brutal method -> delete .git folder and create new git repo like you do before with the project

Comment: This works but @JCorcuera's answer might be cleaner. If you delete the .git folder you will lose all past commit into. The question is do you want to be able to merge the repo back to the original at any point?